# How to set TerminalServiceProfile Path in Windows server 2003 Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I know in Windows 2008 AD, we have msTsProfilePath AD attribute using which we can directly set the terminal service profile path.

But we have windows 2003 AD and i need to set terminal service profile path using C#. 
I came across following article and have come to know from some other articles that terminal service profile path gets stored in userParameters property.

http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes-w2k3.htm#List

Can somebody tell me how to set CtxWFProfilePath in userParameters through C# ?

Thanks,
Nikhil.

**Update:** 
Please refer to this [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/485df45c-de86-4084-8935-4179711bb7f9) where this gentleman "Konrad Neitzel" directed me to some useful links. But as mentioned in the thread, i am finding difficulties in using WTSSetUserConfig method. Any idea ?

Comment: Refer this link on [MSDN Foru](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/485df45c-de86-4084-8935-4179711bb7f9)m for answer i accepted there

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this one too but finally was able to put together a working solution from dozens of different sites. I'm not sure is this exactly what you are needing but hopefully it helps

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "name", "container");
UserPrincipals user = UserPrincipals.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "ad_user_name");

DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);
dirEntry.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesProfilePath", "yourpath");

dirEntry.CommitChanges();
```

You can find all the attributes from this site (another tough thign to find out)
http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/scripting/scripting-server-based-computing-terminal-services-attributes-active-directory-user-objects.html

Comment: That property does not exist unfortunately so this does not work. There is no "TerminalServicesProfilePath" property and even the msTsProfilePath does not exist.